# Actionbar in Android Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am getting below null pointer exception for ActionBar

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

I have used AppCompatActivity extending my Activity and I have changed in my styles.xml in below way

```
item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
```

but still I am getting the same error. I tried changing getActionBar to getSupportActionBar() but still the same error.

I am using these imports

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

I am getting below null pointer exception for ActionBar
Please help.

Comment: Post the code where you are getting error

Comment: add error logs in question

Comment: check your theme ........ in style.xlm

Comment: have you set toolbar as actionbar?

Comment: Assign your toolbar, then setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: Yes that fixed the issue.. Thanks @Raghunandan

Answer (score 0):

I Think you are not using the Appcompact Theme

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
```